# Generate list of <td> elements

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, html-agility-pack

```
     <TD class=date><SPAN id=dtDataId-local0><ABBR title=Saturday>Sat,</ABBR> 02/04/17<BR>08:00 PM</SPAN></TD>
     <TD class=more><A aria-describedby="acDataId-local0 veDataId-local0 dtDataId-local0" id=pl_1000512EE235A45A class="more button button-tertiary flat" href="URL" data-ismoreinfo="0" data-availability="1000512EE235A45A" jquery161006228687738801841="12">SEE</A></TD>
```

How can I acquire a list of all the  elements under the class name of `'date'` and if the date matches `02/04/17` then I would generate a list of all the `<td>` elements 'more' and match the span ID from the `"td class date` to the `td class more`, and if matched `acDataId-local0 veDataId-local0 dtDataId-local0"`, I would acquire the href.

I understand that the loop would somewhat be like:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='table2']//tr"))
{
    foreach (HtmlNode col in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
    { 
        Response.Write(col.InnerText); 
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user7392548 if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this would the trick for you

```
foreach (HtmlNode col in row.SelectNodes("//td[@class='date']"))
{
    if(col.InnerText == "02/04/17")
    {
        foreach (HtmlNode col in row.SelectNodes("//td[@class='more']"))
        {

        }
    }
}
```